# What does the state $a_k a_l^\dagger|0\rangle$ represent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, vacuum, many-body, quantum-states

Consider the action of the operator $a_k a_l^\dagger$ on the vacuum state $$|{\rm vac}\rangle\equiv |0,0,\ldots,0\rangle,$$ the action of $a_l^\dagger$ surely creates one particle in the $l$th state. But next, when $a_k$ acts on the vacuum, since there was no particle in the $k$th state to start with, it should annihilate the vacuum. What does the resulting state $a_k a_l^\dagger|{\rm vac}\rangle$ represent? Is it a vacuum state or a one-particle state? The action of the total number operator gives 0 eigenvalue. I find the result suspicious.

Comment: I am looking at the cannonical quantization of a scalar field and based on the commutator relations the answer is $0$ for $l\neq k$. Can you state what the result you suspect is?

Comment: The action of all linear operators on this state yields $0$.

Comment: @JohnA. After you have created a particle in the l state, nothing annihilates it. Where did it go?

Comment: @solidification It would be good if you read all of the comments to Hyperions answer and also my answer after that. I’d tweak your question because I agree this is indeed the more interesting question

Answer (score 4):

As $a_k a_\ell^\dagger |\text{vac}\rangle= [a_k, a_\ell^\dagger] |\text{vac}\rangle=\delta_{k\ell} |\text{vac}\rangle$, the result is $0$ for $k\ne \ell$ and $|\text{vac}\rangle$ for $k=\ell$.

Comment: I’d be interesting to get an intuition based answer to this because I can’t really answer the “so then what happened to the other particle?” question that immediately follows. Also, I think a more intutive treatment requires gaussian wavepackets and then the answer is not strictly 0. Its proportial to $\int d^3k_1 d^3k_2f_1f_2\delta^3(k-l)$ where the $f$ are gaussian wave packets

Comment: @JohnA. .Nothing "happened" to the other particle, because the action of an operator on a state doesn't correspond to a physical process. One way to be okay with this is to note that $\hat{a}|0\rangle$ is the *zero vector*, which isn't even a quantum state! The zero vector is *not* the state of no particles (that would be the vacuum $|0\rangle$); rather it is not even a quantum state. This *mathematical* action of an operator on a state is just some step in a derivation of an actual physical result and doesn't mean anything on its own.

Comment: Acting with the annihilation operator $a_k$ on a vector in Fock space does not correspond to any physical process. It's a purely mathematical operation. Written in tensor notation, you simply have $(a_k \otimes \mathbf{1})(\mathbf{1} \otimes a_\ell^\dagger)|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle=(a_k \otimes \mathbf{1}) |0\rangle \otimes|\ell\rangle= a_k |0\rangle \otimes |\ell\rangle =0$ as $a_k|0\rangle=0$

Comment: I 100% agree with all this.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer is 100% mathematically and physically correct, I don’t think it satisfies the spirit of the question so I will actually answer a more “real” question: what happens if you have a state peaking at $l$ and you hit it with the $a_k$. The motivation for this is that my professor always says you really have to do stuff with gaussian wavepackets because delta peaked states don’t exist in nature. First define a more useful raising operator (Srednicki 5.6) $$a^\dagger_l=\int d^3k f_l(k) a^\dagger(k)$$ where $f_l(k).  \propto \exp(\frac{-(k-l)^2}{4\sigma^2})$. Then consider the state with momentum sharply peaked on $l$:
$|\psi\rangle= a^\dagger_l|\text{vac}\rangle$. Then, hit this with $a(q)$ where $q$ is what you called $k$ but I am changing it for clarity. Thus we want to answer what $$a(q)|\psi\rangle$$ is. Easily enough, $$a(q)|\psi\rangle= \int d^3k f_l(k) a(q)a^\dagger(k) |\text{vac}\rangle $$
Use commutator relation $$a(q)a^\dagger(k)= a^\dagger(k) a(q) +(2\pi)^32\omega\delta(k-q) $$to obtain $$a(q)|\psi\rangle= \int d^3k f_l(k) (2\pi)^32\omega_l\delta(q-k)|\text{vac}\rangle $$ so we take integral $$a(q)|\psi\rangle\propto  \exp(\frac{-(q-l)^2}{4\sigma^2})(2\pi)^32\omega_l|\text{vac}\rangle $$ which, after normalizing, is just the vacuum. So $$a(q)|\psi\rangle=|\text{vac}\rangle$$ which is somewhat expected. Also, interestingly, in the limit these 2 are infinitely far, the answer changes to $0$. Also, I chose to do this in momentum space but the same argument can be done in position space.

Answer (score 2):

The state $\hat{a}_k\hat{a}_l^{\dagger}|0\rangle$ doesn't represent *anything*.  In fact, since the result of this operation is the *zero* vector, the result isn't even a quantum state (since quantum states are necessarily non-zero). The zero vector is not the state of no particles (that would be the vacuum $|0\rangle$); rather it is not even a quantum state.

Acting with an operator on a state doesn't necessarily (and in fact, *usually* doesn't) correspond to a physical process. Instead, this *mathematical* action of an operator on a state is just some step in a derivation of an actual physical result and doesn't mean anything on its own.

Physically, nothing *happened* to the particle (in state $l$), because the action of $\hat{a}_k$ doesn't correspond to a physical process. This kind of misunderstanding is an unfortunate side effect of the *nomenclature* of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ as "destroying" or "creating" a particle, which makes us think that the action of these operators on states *literally* destroys or creates a particle, whereas that's not (usually) what these mathematical actions mean.

(There are counterexamples: the measurement of an electromagnetic field by a photo-detector removes a photon from the field, and so in the ideal case, this action can be represented as $\hat{a}_k|\psi\rangle$. However, there is a clear physical mechanism by which the particle is "destroyed" in this case.)